# Customer table with last order id - violate normalization?

Tags: normalization

So I'm looking at a customers table that has a relationship with an orders table. There is a trigger in place to set the last_order_id field of the customers table whenever a order it placed. Does having a last_order_id violate normalization rules? Specifically 3rd normal form? And what would be a better methodology for this type of work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No it does not violate normalization rules because NF forms are defined in terms of dependency rules that involve ONLY A SINGLE TABLE.

Obviously, it creates a form of redundancy in your database, because as has been said, the "last order" can be derived by looking at the ORDERS table, but that is a form of redundancy that the traditional normal forms do not seek to address.  Traditional normal forms up to BCNF consider functional dependencies only, and since it is presumably indeed the case that your customerid will unambiguously determine the corresponding last_order (*), having the last_order in the customers table is even the only place where the NF forms will say it belongs.

(*) if it can be the case that a customer has no orders at all, then there will be nothing to put in this column.  You will probably use NULL in that case, and there are those who say that this is in itself a violation of 1NF.  The more traditional version of normalization theory glosses over NULL cases completely.

EDIT

I noticed I have forgotten to answer the bonus question "what would be a better methodology for this type of work".  IMO, the proper way, at least theoretically, to address these kinds of situation is by using materialized views.  Define the aggregate query that computes the last_order for each customer as a view, and have the DBMS keep a physical record of its value ("materialize the view").  This way, the redundancy in the design has been brought under control (it is now entirely managed by the DBMS itself).  Unfortunately, few DBMS's will be able to support this for views that involve aggregation.  The rulesets of what is possible and what isn't, in this area, for a given DBMS, are rather diverse and extremely ad-hoc.

The trigger you say you already have is the next best thing if materialized view isn't an option.  Or remove the redundancy altogether and just recompute the last_order from the ORDERS table whenever it is needed, if that is feasible given the applicable performance requirements/expectations.

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of normalisation is to structure the schema so that each piece of data is held exactly once.  Given that the last order number can be found by referencing the order table at run time then I would say the current design is denormalised.

I wouldn't necessarily conclude that this is a problem, however.  A beautiful, normalised, logical data model has to be implemented on messy, imperfect, physical equipment. This has limitations which have to be dealt with. One way is to denormalise data. If this is done as a conscious act with an intended outcome, and has been tested, then I don't see that it is necessarily a problem. Denormalisation due to premature optimisation and poor analysis *is* a problem and should be avoided.

As for alternatives, I can think of two. An index on Orders with customer_id and order_id as keys will give very quick access to the last order number:

```
select top 1
  order_id
from orders
where customer_id = <current customer id>
order by order_id desc;
```

The second is to add a flag to Orders to show which is the latest for each customer, and add constraints and indexes appropriately. This is not very different for the current solution, either in normalisation purity or performance characteristics.

---

Comment:

> I'm having a hard time understanding..

Response:

There are two types of model - logical and physical. In a perfect world the logical model is written without giving thought to any implementation considerations whatsoever. It can be to whatever esoteric [normal form](http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/25209) you desire. Like an elegant proof in theoretical mathematics it is "beautiful".

The physical model, however, has to recognise that IO takes time, CPUs are expensive, memory is strictly limited and there is never enough of it. The physical model has to deliver a database which is actually useful to the application's users. One technique for accommodating the limitations which reality imposes is demormalisation.

I would suggest that holding the last order ID in the customer table is an example of denormalisation for this purpose. It is done to allow the system to give quick response to users, with the knowledge that it adds complexity to the system, and therefore it is acceptable in the physical model.

Comment: While it is obvious that this answer is written "with the heart in the right place" (and I have every bit of sympathy for the spirit in which it is written), technically speaking it is completely wrong.  The kind of redundancy that consists of physically as well as logically recording values that can be obtained by performing aggregations on certain other components of the database, is not addressed by any piece of formal normalization theory I know.